# Problem running commands with 'sudo' in Bash script

Tags: shell-script, permissions, sudo, error-handling

I have an installation script which appears to work fine and doesn't output any errors, but when running a command with one of the newly installed packages, I'm told I don't have permission to access a key file (`/home/test/.config/configstore/bower-github.json`).

However, when I install the packages using the *exact* same commands from the script, but run manually in the terminal one by one (outside of the script), everything works as expected, with no complaints about permissions.

What is it about the script that is causing a permission issue?

## System info

`Linux test 5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 4 14:58:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

## Commands to run script

`bash adapt.sh`
`sudo bash adapt.sh`

(I've tried both in separate tests on fresh VM installs; the result was the same)

## Script

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG=~/adapt/LOG.txt

# Print description
echo
echo "Adapt installation for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
echo "### Supported until April 2023 ###"
sleep 2
echo
echo "The Adapt authoring tool, CLI and dependencies will be installed."
sleep 2
echo -n "Would you like to continue? [y/N] "
read input
echo
if [[ $input == "y" || $input == "Y" ]]; then
    echo "Creating and moving to new Adapt directory ..."
    sleep 2
    mkdir ~/adapt
    cd ~/adapt
    touch LOG.txt
    echo "Updating software package repos ..."
    sudo apt-get update >> /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Installing Git ..."
    sudo apt-get -y install git-all >> $LOG 2>&1
    $(which curl >> /dev/null 2>&1)
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        sudo apt-get -y install curl >> $LOG 2>&1
    fi
    echo "Installing Node.js v12.x (LTS) ..."
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash - >> $LOG 2>&1
    sudo apt-get -y install nodejs >> $LOG 2>&1
    echo "Installing Grunt ..."
    sudo npm install -g grunt-cli >> $LOG 2>&1
    echo "Installing the Adapt CLI ..."
    sudo npm install -g adapt-cli >> $LOG 2>&1
    echo "Installing MongoDB and starting mongod service ..."
    wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add - >> $LOG 2>&1
    sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list >> /dev/null 2>&1
    sudo apt-get update >> /dev/null 2>&1
    sudo apt-get -y install mongodb-org >> $LOG 2>&1
        sudo service mongod start >> $LOG 2>&1
    echo "Installing the Adapt authoring tool ..."
    git clone https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring.git >> $LOG 2>&1
    cd adapt_authoring
    sudo npm install --production >> $LOG 2>&1
    sudo node install
else
    echo "Exiting..."
fi

echo "Refer to 'LOG.txt' for more information."
echo
```

## Error

```
test@test:~/adapt$ adapt create course
/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/test/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:35)
    at Configstore.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
    at new Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:45)
    at readCachedConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
    at defaultConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/adapt-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/home/test/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
}
```

Comment: What is `adapt create course`? What does that have to do with your script? You said you get an error from the script, so why are you showing an error from some other command?

Comment: Did the file get created during a `sudo ...` invocation, such that the file is now owned by root and inaccessible to your non-root user?

Comment: @terdon I didn't say I got an error from the script. I got the error when trying to use a program installed with the script. The program in question is `adapt-cli`. This _installs_ fine. But _only when installed via the script_ the command `adapt [...]` shows the permission error. 

After carrying out some more research, I believe it could be something to do with the way I've run the script; possibly I should have used `./adapt.sh` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried changing the ownership ..

```
chown test.test /home/test/.config/configstore/bower-github.json
```

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as my own answer/workaround involves the same: -
`chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config`

`chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm`